# Conditions for the existence of moments of the supremum of a random variable

Tags: random-variables, supremum-and-infimum, moment-generating-functions

let $X_1, X_2,\dots X_n$ denote a sequence of $n$ iid random variables with the first $k$ moments of $F_X$ exist. Under what conditions (if at all) do the first $k$ moments of the random variable $X_{\text{max}}=\max\{\,X_1,\ldots,X_n\,\}$ exist?

I want to know this since I would like to apply the CLT to the mean of $M$ such maximums and before I do that, I need to verify that the moments of the variables used to construct the mean have such finite $k$ first moments.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean $\{X_i\}$ is a *sequence* of random variables?

Comment: In what sense should $S = \sup_i x_i$ exist? It is always a random variable in $(-\infty, \infty]$.

Comment: @user251257 The question is not whether $S$ exists, but whether its moments exist.

Comment: @NormalHuman ah. somehow I oversaw that. sorry .@icaspi

Comment: well. I would say dominated convergence theorem or monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you all. I re-edited the question. I hope it is now clearer.